# PHP DOM preserve Html structure

Tags: php, dom

I have this code

```
 $strhtml = file_get_contents('05001400300320100033100.html');
 $dochtml = new DOMDocument();
 $dochtml->loadHTML($strhtml);
 $elm = $dochtml->getElementById('upPanelActuciones');
 $tag = $elm->tagName;
 $cnt = $elm->nodeValue;
  echo $tag. ' - '. $cnt;
```

so.. Im getting this:

Detalle del Registro Datos del Proceso InformaciÃƒÂ³n RadicaciÃƒÂ³n del Proceso Despacho Ponente 003 JUZGADO MUNICIPAL - Civil JUEZ TERCERO CIVIL MUNICIPAL ClasificaciÃƒÂ³n del Proceso Tipo Clase Recurso UbicaciÃƒÂ³n del Expediente De EjecuciÃƒÂ³n Ejecutivo Singular SIN TIPO DE RECURSO Archivo Contenido de RadicaciÃƒÂ³n Demandante(s) Demandado(s) Â 3354216 - HORACIO DE JESUS JIMENEZ ARANGO Â 70128088 - RAFAEL ANGEL HERNANDEZ OROZCO Contenido Actuaciones del Proceso Fecha de ActuaciÃƒÂ³n ActuaciÃƒÂ³n AnotaciÃƒÂ³n Fecha Inicia TÃƒÂ©rmino Fecha Finaliza TÃƒÂ©rmino Fecha de Registro 18 Nov 2011 ARCHIVO DEFINITIVO CAJA 267 18 Nov 2011 27 Sep 2010 RECEPCIÃƒÂ“N MEMORIAL OJ F2 27 Sep 2010 21 Sep 2010 RECEPCIÃƒÂ“N MEMORIAL OJ F1 21 Sep 2010 10 May 2010 RETIRO DEMANDA - ART.88 PEDRO NEL OSPINA 10 May 2010 03 May 2010 FIJACION ESTADO ACTUACIÃƒÂ“N REGISTRADA EL 03/05/2010 A LAS 11:32:40. 05 May 2010 05 May 2010 03 May 2010 03 May 2010 AUTO RECHAZA DEMANDA T.4 03 May 2010 07 Apr 2010 RADICACIÃƒÂ“N DE PROCESO ACTUACIÃƒÂ“N DE RADICACIÃƒÂ“N DE PROCESO REALIZADA EL 07/04/2010 A LAS 17:54:12 07 Apr 2010 07 Apr 2010 07 Apr 2010

Just a plain text.

So, My question is: is there a way to preserve the Html estructure, I mean the Td and Tr inside "upPanelActuciones" or any other tag or attribute that I want?

Thanks in advance for your help! .

Comment: You need to use http://php.net/htmlspecialchars to print out the result with tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `nodeValue` property will get you only the text contents of that node.

Use the [`saveXml()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) method instead:

```
$elm = $dochtml->getElementById('upPanelActuciones');

print $dochtml->saveXml($elm);
```

Comment: Hi @One Trick Pony im getting this: Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in C:\AppServ\www\video01\sector2\dom3.php on line 25

Comment: Oh yes, it's saveXml, forgot about that. Apparently in saveHtml(), the node argument was added in php 5.3.6, you must have an older version